# JavaScript: Remove null/undefined/empty attributes from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects, want to remove null/undefined/empty elements...

**Example:-**

```
[
  {
    'Name': 'Sorav',
    'Phone': '9090909090',
    'Class': 'A',
    'Age': '25'
  },
  {
    'Name': 'Gaurav',
    'Phone': '',
    'Class': 'A',
    'Age': '25'
  },
  {
    'Name': 'Stack',
    'Phone': '',
    'Class': 'A',
    'Age': null
  }
]
```

**Expected Output:-**

```
[
  {
    'Name': 'Sorav',
    'Phone': '9090909090',
    'Class': 'A',
    'Age': '25'
  },
  {
    'Name': 'Gaurav',
    'Class': 'A',
    'Age': '25'
  },
  {
    'Name': 'Stack',
    'Class': 'A'
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use lodash's `pickBy`:

```js
let data = [
  {
    'Name': 'Sorav',
    'Phone': '9090909090',
    'Class': 'A',
    'Age': '25'
  },
  {
    'Name': 'Gaurav',
    'Phone': '',
    'Class': 'A',
    'Age': '25'
  },
  {
    'Name': 'Stack',
    'Phone': '',
    'Class': 'A',
    'Age': null
  }
];

data = _.map(data, e => 
  _.pickBy(e, _.identity)
);

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Another solution using JavaScript `.reduce`:

```js
let data = [
  {
    'Name': 'Sorav',
    'Phone': '9090909090',
    'Class': 'A',
    'Age': '25'
  },
  {
    'Name': 'Gaurav',
    'Phone': '',
    'Class': 'A',
    'Age': '25'
  },
  {
    'Name': 'Stack',
    'Phone': '',
    'Class': 'A',
    'Age': null
  }
];

data = data.map(item => 
  Object.entries(item).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    if (value) {
      acc[key] = value;
    }
    return acc;
  }, {})
);

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by looping over your array of objects, and checking if the value in each key is empty:

```
const objs = [
  {
    'Name': 'Sorav',
    'Phone': '9090909090',
    'Class': 'A',
    'Age': '25'
  },
  {
    'Name': 'Gaurav',
    'Phone': '',
    'Class': 'A',
    'Age': '25'
  },
  {
    'Name': 'Stack',
    'Phone': '',
    'Class': 'A',
    'Age': null
  }
]

for (let i = 0; i < objs.length; i++ ) {
    for (el in objs[i]) {
        if (objs[i][el] === null || objs[i][el] === '')
        delete objs[i][el]
    }
}

console.log(objs);
```

Result will be:

```
[
  { Name: 'Sorav', Phone: '9090909090', Class: 'A', Age: '25' },
  { Name: 'Gaurav', Class: 'A', Age: '25' },
  { Name: 'Stack', Class: 'A' }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data is from a JSON string, it can be filtered with `JSON.parse` or `JSON.stringify` :

```js
var json = JSON.stringify( [ { 'Name': 'Sorav', 'Phone': '9090909090', 'Class': 'A', 'Age': '25' }, { 'Name': 'Gaurav', 'Phone': '', 'Class': 'A', 'Age': '25' }, { 'Name': 'Stack', 'Phone': '', 'Class': 'A', 'Age': null } ] )

var result = JSON.parse(json, (k, v) => v === '' || v === null ? void 0 : v)

console.log( result )
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that array is called `array`:

```
const filtered = array.map(elem => {
  for (const key of Object.keys(elem)) {
    if (!elem[key]) {
      delete elem[key]
    }
  }

  return elem
}).filter(elem => Object.keys(elem).length > 0)
```

You could also use a `reduce` to combine the `map` and `filter` steps and avoid the second iteration over `array`

Comment: You mutate the input. It's not wrong, but it can easily lead to bugs/unexpected behaviour in some completely unrelated part of the program, especially with less experienced devs. That's why the concept of immutability got so big. Personally, I avoid the `delete` keyword because changing the hidden class of an object over and over may ruin the engines optimization. And I use `delete` only on objects that serve as dictionaries/hashmaps `const itemById = {}, itemByName = {}`